# python3-saml and Azure AD - missing a point

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure, single-sign-on, saml

Good afternoon experts,

I have a Django web application (it is not internet-facing) and so far I used the `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` to authenticate the users.
However I want to integrate this webapp to an existing SSO solution (like Azure AD) so I thought **python3-saml** would be a good library to be used (more specifically I use **python3-saml-django** but it is just a wrapper around **python3-saml**).
Probably I am missing some fundamental point as I don't really understand how this should work.

When I used `ModelBackend` then I had a login form where the user could type their username+password which was checked against Django database and the authentication was completed. Should the same work with SSO too? i.e. the login form appears, the user will type their credentials but they will be checked in Azure AD instead of Django auth tables? Or the custom login form of that specific auth solution (in this case Azure AD -> Microsoft login form) should be displayed...?

The **LOGIN_URL** setting is configured in my Django app so if no user is logged in then automatically my login form appears.
Also I set the **AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS** setting and it points only to `django_saml.backends.SamlUserBAckend`.

I configured AZure AD (registered the app and added a user, I tested it in Azure AD console) hopefully correctly. I also populated python3-saml's settings.json with login/logout URL, etc.

Whenever I try to log in with the Azure AD user I got an auth error (the user and password did).

I am just wondering if somebody could shed some light please how this should work? Can I debug the SAML requests / responses?

Answer (score 0):

- auth is token based in azure ad and it will redirect the user to the microsoft login.   You will receive an auth token which then you can use to for authorization and providing secure pages.
- First register your app in azure portal in azure active directory and also create a user flow.
- Then download MSAL for python (using pip) which is used for auth using azure ad for python.
- The basic architecture is that when the user tries to login the Microsoft login page will be shown, after signing in your app will receive a token which then you should use to show the logged in pages.

**References:**

[quickstart for auth in python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-python)

[userflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview)

[MSAL Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Developing-an-AAD-B2C-app-with-MSAL-Python)

Comment: Eventually I tried to use django-saml2-auth and djangosaml2 libraries which kind of worked but after successfully authenticated in Azure AD but I got in to a redirect loop. BTW thanks for the help!

Comment: Can the MSAL library be used with OpenLink, etc? The reason wy I want to use python3-saml that it can support more Identity Provider.